# Does our brain really "flip" images perceived by our eyes?

Tags: vision, perception

I know a similar question has been asked and this is closely related to cognitive science. However, I want to know whether is there any mechanism or structure in the visual cortex which is proved to be flipping the images upside down.

Comment: I recommend you go over to cogsci.se and have a look at this [thread](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/337/why-would-the-brain-flip-the-images-perceived-by-your-eyes). Its basically the same question and the answers are pretty nice including some references.

Comment: @Chris.. i wonder why cognitive sciences is a separate SE. It is a part of biology.

Comment: @WYSIWYG It is true that many questions asked here on Biology could equally be asked on cognitive science. However, there are many questions in cognitive science that are part of psychology and therefore has nothing to do with biology. How are we supposed to treat a question that is a duplicate on another SE website? Should we close it as off-topic even if it is not really off-topic? The comments are not the right place for having this discussion. Sorry :)